# Thermodynamics Relations

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have found some thermodynamics relations in the Solid State Physics book by Ashcroft and Mermin. It's written $$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \mu} \right)_T = n \textrm{, } \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_{\mu} = s  $$ where $p$ is the pressure of the system, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $T$ is the temperature, $n$ is the number density and $s$ is the entropy per unit volume.

I tried to prove this relation by writing $$p=-u+Ts+\mu n$$ but I could not see anything useful at this stage. If anyone can suggest me, I would appreciate it a lot! (Note that this is not a homework)

Comment: Which chapter in Ashcroft and Mermin?

Comment: It is the equation 2.100 in chapter 2 :)

Comment: I see. You need to go back to earlier in the chapter where the thermodynamics of free electron gases are discussed and start there.

Comment: Do these relationships hold only for the fermion system? Are they not for general case?

Comment: The other place to look is Appendix B, and go from there.

Comment: Can you differentiate wrt to $\mu$ the linear relationship you wrote? What do you get?